# Are there names for referring to the top or bottom numbers in a time signature?

Tags: terminology, time-signatures

In a time signature of 3/4 (three by four), what is the name given to the `3` and the `4`? I know it in my own language, but can't find the answer for the English equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The entire symbol that defines the meter of a measure of music is called a *time signature*.

To my knowledge, English does not have specific words to refer to the top and bottom numbers, though some people may use the words 'numerator' and 'denominator', respectively, as if it were a mathematical fraction. I do not recommend this (since time signatures have nothing to do with fractions).

If I needed to give names to the top and bottom numbers I would call them 'measure length' and 'subdivision quantifier,' but usually it's not necessary to do this--or at least, we have enough other ways in English to talk about musical meter and the time signature that it's not necessary to refer to those numbers directly.

Comment: I meant measure. I sometime confuse the music terminology names in English. That's very odd for me to know since I am used to have specific names for that. By curiosity, if I was to translate the names I am used to use to to English, the `numerator` would be `unit of tempo` and the `denominator` would be `unit of measure`. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Time signatures have everything to do with fractions.

Comment: @GeneralNuisance I graciously invite you to support your argument instead of making an unhelpful contradiction.

Comment: I thought it was something that was generally accepted, but I will explain (a quick google search has brought my attention to that it's not, so it's worth my time). A fraction is made of a numerator and a denominator. Numerator, as my math text book defines it, is how many "things" are in a fraction. Denominator, it defines as "the type of things" in a fraction. A time signature describes a measure. It doesn't necessarily have to equal 1 to equal one whole measure, however, when you think of it this way, the parallels are strong. Fractions can be equivalent...

Comment: ...like 3/4 and 6/8, and while musically they are different rhythms with different beats, notationally, it is correct to write a song in 6/8 in 3/4. The time signature describes a whole measure. Even before I learned that, apparently, the connection between fractions and time sigs was not mainstream understanding, I would have (and did) flag you with the statement "time signatures have nothing to do with fractions." Except in extremely informal (and/or teaching) settings, I wouldn't refer to the numbers in a time sig as Numerator/Denominator, but I don't think it's fair to sever the concepts.

Comment: I regret the wording "worth my time" in the first comment. I'm not trying to come off as rude.

Comment: Thank you. I see your point and can appreciate those parallels. I usually think of a fraction as a ratio or a quotient, rather than the two separate attributes that describe that quotient. Both are valid interpretations, of course. My argument is mainly that applying concepts of elementary math to musical meter can easily cause confusion to a learning musician. 6/8 and 3/4 are mathematically _and_ durationally equivalent, but are _musically_ different, and should not be played _or_ notated in the same way (beaming, chiefly).

Comment: 6/8 and 3/4 are equivalent fractions in math, but those time signatures are NOT the same! You could write a 3/4 song in measures of four beats, but it would not be a 4/4 song...

Answer (score 5):

If you really need single words, I'd recommend 'count' and 'quantum'. If it isn't obvious which is which, then this is a bad suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

There are no specific names, although that would be nice. The numerator is beats per bar. The denominator is the note duration of a beat. So 3/4 means 3 beats per bar, where quarter note is a beat.

Also, although tempo is specificed in beats per minute, it actually means QUARTER notes per minute. Even if the beat is not a quarter note per the time signature.

Comment: Tempo can be specified with something other than quarter notes, and in the absence of specification I would be loath to assume that "40 bpm" for a piece in 3/8 means anything other than forty 8ths per minute (for example).

Comment: That last part isn't really true--tempo markings are either going to be unambiguously marked for a quarter-note-beat meter, or will include a note value to show what kind of note gets what BPM value. For example, 6/8 time will be marked q.=60 or e=180.

Comment: I'm pretttttty sure that if there's no q.=99 or e=99 specified, then the sTANDARD is quarter notes per minute regardless of time signature's beat duration...

and I'm absolutely positive that in a midi file, tempo values are ALWAYS quarter notes per minute regardless of time signature.

Comment: In musical notation, a metronome marking is always specified as "M.M." (for "Maelzel's Metronome") followed by a picture of a note, an equals sign and a number.  The note may or may not be a quarter note.  6/8 time is usually 2 beats per measure, not 6.  Dance music is almost always either 4/4 (quarter note beat), 3/4 (quarter note beat), 2/4 (quarter note beat) or 6/8 (dotted quarter note beat).

Comment: The MIDI spec should NOT be used as a guide to real music. Seriously. A piece of music in 5/16 with an ambiguous time signature is NEVER going refer to the quarter note, since it's practically useless for figuring out how to actually play the thing. It's either going to be the entire measure, an eighth note, or a dotted eighth.

Comment: I'll grant ya that.  All I'm tryin' to say is that sheet music CAN be ambiguous like that.  And if it's not spec'd it's safer to assume BPM=quarter note/min rather than "denominator" per min...  I'm positive I've seen ambiguous sheet music like that.

Comment: My point (and the last I'll say on this) is that while meter and beat may be ambiguous, a metronome marking should be interpreted as "beats per minute" if no other indication is given. _Then_ you can start figuring out which notational value is supposed to get the beat, and that part may or may not correspond with the bottom number in the time signature--you still have to go through the process of figuring that out. But the metronome marking should be considered _beats_ per measure, which may or may not be quarter notes. It's the _meter_ that's ambiguous.